# Aggregate an Aggregate

Tags: sql-server

In MSSQL I'm trying to return the number of rows where the count of a certain activity exceeds X and has occurred more then y number of times in a month.

This query tells me how many times on a given day for the current month the activity has occurred.

```
SELECT COUNT(DATEPART(DAY,myDATETIME))as dayCount,DATEPART(DAY,myDATETIME)as theDAY, Activity

FROM ALL_Activities

WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,myDATETIME)= DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())

AND DATEPART(MONTH,myDATETIME)= DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())

AND Activity = 'The door opened'

GROUP BY (DATEPART(DAY,myDATETIME)), Activity

HAVING COUNT(DATEPART(DAY,myDATETIME)) > 0 AND ???????
```

---

```
dayCount, theDAY, Activity

3   19  The door opened

7   18  The door opened

7   17  The door opened

1   15  The door opened

2   14  The door opened

1   13  The door opened

5   12  The door opened

1   11  The door opened

10  10  The door opened

4   9   The door opened

1   8   The door opened

2   7   The door opened
```

What I'm trying to end up with is a query that returns the activity when it has happened at least X times a day more then Y times a month such that A single row matching the criteria returned would have the total number of occurrences, the total number of days, and the activity. Is it possible to do this strictly within SQL?

```
44, 12, The door opened
```

If not that, then even the rows that meet the criteria would help. Meaning maybe return the rows when the number of days in the given month is >=5 where the times per day >=1. I tried using some combination of sub queries, @@ROWCOUNT, and other things, but couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This report will give you all the information.
Use it as a base and filter it however you want.

```
declare @day_activities_threshold int = 10 

select      activity
           ,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,[day]),0)                                            as [month]
           ,count(*)                                                                            as activity_days
           ,count(case when day_activities >= @day_activities_threshold then 1 end)             as activity_days_over_threshold
           ,sum(day_activities)                                                                 as month_activities
           ,sum(case when day_activities >= @day_activities_threshold then day_activities end)  as month_activities_over_threshold

from       (select      activity 
                       ,cast (mydatetime as date)   as [day]
                       ,count(*)                    as day_activities

            from        all_activities

            group by    activity
                       ,cast (mydatetime as date)
            ) t

group by    activity
           ,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,[day]),0)

having      count(*) > ...  

order by    activity
           ,[month]
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is really close to what I am looking for in that it presents a data grid showing the data and identifying how many days  an activity has exceeded a daily count threshold by month. I'll see if I can refine it further to return only those activities in the current month that exceed the daily count threshold and the number of  days in a month threshold.

Comment: if there were a way to add HAVING activity_days > Y this might be it.

Comment: activity_days per months? see updated answer

Comment: Or do you need it for activity_days_over_threshold?

Comment: No I think you have it. I made the same edit right after I made the comment. Testing again.

Comment: If I change the day_activities_threshold from 1 to 2 and I have the having count(*) 10, I expect no rows returned because there must be at least 11 days where the daily count is >=2. If you look at the data there are only 8 days where the daily occurrence is >=2. Still the query returns 12 days.

Comment: This is why asked if you need activity_days_over_threshold for the HAVING.

Comment: `HAVING count(case when day_activities >= @day_activities_threshold then 1 end) > ...`

Answer (score 1):

Using  **[`with common_table_expression()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** and `count()` **[`over()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)**: we can get a running total for the count.

query:

```
with cte as (
  select distinct
      TheDate= convert(varchar(10),convert(date,mydatetime),120)
    , TheDay = datepart(day,mydatetime)
    , DailyActivityCount = count(*) over (
          partition by convert(date,mydatetime), activity
          )
    , runningActivityCount = count(*) over (
          partition by activity 
          order by convert(date,mydatetime)
          )
    , Activity
  from all_activities
  where activity = 'The door opened'
    and mydatetime >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
    and mydatetime < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
  )
select 
    *
  from cte
  --where runningActivityCount > 12
  order by TheDay
```

rextester results: http://rextester.com/WOW38735

```
+------------+--------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|  TheDate   | TheDay | DailyActivityCount | runningActivityCount |    Activity     |
+------------+--------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| 2017-01-07 |      7 |                  2 |                    2 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-08 |      8 |                  1 |                    3 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-09 |      9 |                  4 |                    7 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-10 |     10 |                 10 |                   17 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-11 |     11 |                  1 |                   18 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-12 |     12 |                  5 |                   23 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-13 |     13 |                  1 |                   24 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-14 |     14 |                  2 |                   26 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-15 |     15 |                  1 |                   27 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-17 |     17 |                  7 |                   34 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-18 |     18 |                  7 |                   41 | The door opened |
| 2017-01-19 |     19 |                  3 |                   44 | The door opened |
+------------+--------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

update based on question in comment:

```
Declare @Activity varchar(64) = 'The door opened';
Declare @DailyThreshold int = 2;
Declare @Month varchar(7) =  '2017-01'; 
Declare @NthDay int = 5; -- for more then 5 days in a month(Y)


;with countCte as (
  select distinct
      TheMonth= convert(varchar(7),convert(date,mydatetime),120)
    , TheDate= convert(varchar(10),convert(date,mydatetime),120)
    , TheDay = datepart(day,mydatetime)
    , Activity
    , DailyActivityCount = count(*) over (
        partition by convert(date,mydatetime), activity
          )
    , runningActivityCount = count(*) over (
        partition by convert(varchar(7),convert(date,mydatetime),120), activity 
        order by convert(date,mydatetime)
          )
    , MonthlyActivityCount = count(*) over (
        partition by convert(varchar(7),convert(date,mydatetime),120), activity
          )

  from all_activities
  where activity = @Activity
    and mydatetime >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
    and mydatetime < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
  )
, cte as (
    select *
      , rn = row_number() over (
          partition by Activity 
          order by TheDate
          )
      --, 
      from countCte
      where 1=1
        and DailyActivityCount > @DailyThreshold
        and TheMonth = @Month
)
select 
    top 1
    *
  from cte
  where rn > @NthDay
  order by TheDay
```

Comment: I'm having some syntax issues try to get this work. Line 8 "order by is looking for a ")". If I place that at the end of line 7 after partition by actiivity it seems to resolve that. Line 11 however i looking for "(" or "AS"

Comment: ok, I guess MSSMS see syntax errors that do not exist. This too is very helpful. I need to prune this down to one row predicated on a daily occurrence threshold of X and a number of days it occurred threshold of Y for the current month. If activity a occurred at least twice a day(X) for more then 5 days in a month(Y), show me the row including the total number of occurrences and number of days for the month

Comment: @NewtoCloud Well since it isn't January anymore, there isn't test data for "the current month" anymore. Updated the rextester to use January instead of getting the current month.

Comment: With DailyThreshold set to 1 and NthDay set to 5, I'm getting one row returned telling me on the 17th there were 7 occurrences where the door opened with a cumulative total of 34 to that point and a total of 44 for the month and rn=6. While its true, 7 occurrences on the 17th, cumulative is 34 and the month total is 44, its not really what I'm interested in. With the settings mentioned, I expect the row to only show if there are more then 5 days where the door opened at least once showing 12 (number of days this happened more then once), and the 44, the total number of times it happened